# Same code in every viewdidload

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have the same code in every ViewController, it sets the backgroundcolor of the ViewControllers' view and it changes the backbutton and the titleview of the navbaritem. 
Is there a way to avoid this?

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 24)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navbar_BackButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTabbed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -10)];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

[navbarItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];

[navbarItem setTitleView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navbar_Title.png"]]];

[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Login_Background.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a perfect case for subclassing.

Create a subclass of `UIViewController` which overrides the `viewDidLoad` method performing your code, and then make every other view controller that need such behavior a subclass of it.

Comment: You probably also need one for UITableViewController.

Comment: Correct, but you can inherit from the same custom view controller and manually conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. I'd probably go with this solution rather than creating two different parent classes doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1) Create a common base class that all of your view controller extend from. The downside is you probably need two - one for `UIViewController` and one for `UITableViewController`. In these two classes you would put this common code.

2) Create a "helper" class that you call from every `viewDidLoad`. You still need to add a line of code to every `viewDidLoad` but at least it is only one line. If you need to change the color or whatever, you only change the one class instead of every view controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of the power of inheritance in Object Oriented Programming!

Create a subclass of `UIViewController` to act as your base view controller (you could call it BaseViewController, even!)

Then, make all of your other view controllers a subclass of this base view controller instead of `UIViewController`. Since these subclasses will call `[super viewDidLoad]`, they will inherit the code in the base view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, which should contain your appearance code!